# Angular [Innerhtml] renders static files different from webapi response

Tags: html, angular, innerhtml, eml

Need to display HTML file content in a DIV, works in static file, fails on dynamic file.

### What Works:

I have an EML file, which I suspected I had to parse. 
Renaming file extension to HTML, as is pleasantly rendered it somewhat decent, with all tags removed and formatted correctly, **if served from static file**.

```
public getOneFileStatic(fn: string): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get(fn, { responseType: 'text' })
      .pipe(tap(_ => console.log('== getOneFileStatic ')));
  }
```

and  called simply:

```
svc.getOneFileStatic('/assets/files/eml-test.html')
            .subscribe(x => {                        
                    this.theinner = x;
                });
```

and the template is

```
<div class="card-block">
      <div [innerHTML]="theinner | safeHtml" style="width: 100%"></div>
</div>
```

### What doesn't, and shows raw text with tags

Then tried the dynamic way to return from a webapi:

```
public getOneFile(fn: string): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get( this.baseUrl + '/api/ServerFiles/GetStream/' + fn , { responseType: 'text' })
      .pipe(tap(_ => console.log('== getOneFile '))
      );
  }
```

results are a stream of text with all tags and MIME content dumped as is.

### I looked into

I checked content headers and tried: text, blob etc., also application/octet.
But they all come across fine and are displayed raw with the HTML tags never honored.

Headers:
When static file is served

```
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified
X-Powered-By: Express
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Accept-Ranges: bytes
ETag: W/"cb81-Rb8BCAxZvy4eWO/lkggYEFPkXzo"
Date: Wed, 16 Jan 2019 21:33:45 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
```

when the dynamic file comes across:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Thu, 17 Jan 2019 00:52:35 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Server: Kestrel
Content-Length: 97197
Vary: Origin
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:4200
```

Note: there is no Content-Type header in case of static. But I need to supply one in my server code when streaming file content, which is Kestrel and in .Net Code.

Comment: try this `responseType: 'document'`

Comment: Tried 'document' response type, no change, same result.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try to [sanitize the resulting *raw text with tags*](https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/DomSanitizer#bypasssecuritytrusthtml).

Check out the [Angular Sanizitation API example](https://angular.io/guide/security#sanitization-example) (basic but might be enough).